# Create a fragment inside an activity

Tags: java, android, layout, android-activity, fragment

In my my main activity layout(first layout) I have dynamically set up text views. Now, when these text views are clicked, I want to display another layout(second layout) again having text views(dynamically set). When these text views are clicked I want the text of this text view of this second layout to be set as the text of the text view of the first layout which was clicked.

For eg.

first layout -> [click] [click] ->be the two text views in the layout. Suppose I click the first, then I want to display

[english] [maths] [science]. And suppose I click on english then I want to set the screen to display the first layout again but replacing the text of the view clicked

first layout -> [english] [click].

**Now The Problem**
I have set up the first layout as main_layout. Now I need to know how can a display the second layout in my fragment_layout and then return back to the main_activity. I want to save the instance of the main_layout as it goes from main to fragment and back to main.

**Function called on clicking first layout's text view**

```
         View.OnClickListener timetable_click_listen = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View timetable_viewtext) {

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_time_table);


        int no_subjects;

        /*opens the database and finds out the number of subjects user has entered
        Opening database and getting the number of subjects*/
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",MODE_PRIVATE,null);     

        if(db==null)
        {
            Log.d("Error in TimeTable","There was a error in Opening Database");
        }

        else{
            Log.d("Inside TimeTable Onclick","Opening Database");
        }

        Cursor c= db.rawQuery("SELECT Num_subjects FROM DETAILS;",null);

        c.moveToFirst();

        no_subjects = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Num_subjects"));

        c.close();

        /*Getting the names of the subjects so as to put that name
         * as the button's text
         */

        String[] name = new String[no_subjects];

        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM SUBJECTS;",null);

        c.moveToFirst();

        for(int i=0;i<no_subjects;i++)
        {   
            name[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        c.close();
        db.close();

        LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.timetable_fragment);
        TextView ed;
        List<TextView> allEds = new ArrayList<TextView>();


        for (int i = 0; i < no_subjects; i++) {   

            ed = new TextView(TimeTable.this);

            allEds.add(ed);

            ed.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            ed.setId(1000+i);

            ed.setText(name[i]);

            tempId = timetable_viewtext.getId();

            ed.setClickable(true);
            ed.setOnClickListener(subname_click_listen);

            ((LinearLayout)linearlayout).addView(ed);

        }

    }
};
```

Now I am not understanding what to do in the function of the second layout's view.onclick()

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code. This is a really fundamental problem and there are loads of resources online to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a Fragments Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example)

Comment: @billynomates sir, I have added some of my code.

Comment: This is just getting info from a database. It's got nothing to do with your Fragment. I suggest reading the Fragments developer guide (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) or following the link I posted above).

Comment: Sir the database code is irrelevant to my problem. Sorry that I posted that. I should have edited it. My problem is I am not understanding how to implement the second the subname_click_listen (2nd last line of my code)

Comment: Why are you adding an onClickListener inside the onClickListener of another View? Also that's a different problem to the one you described above. I think you need to start a new question.

Comment: because when the first view is clicked it sets up a layout having textviews whose property has to be set -> on click property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a `FragmentManager` and a `FragmentTransaction`.  To do this you will need to extend the Fragment class.  For example, you might want to make a Fragment to display each layout.  These fragments will have their own layout file so you can customize how they look.  You will need to provide a container to hold the fragments.  I used a `FrameLayout` called `fragment_container`.  To initialize the fragment, use the `FragmentTransaction.add()` method and use the `FragmentTransaction.replace()` method to switch between them.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Check out the API for more info: [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)